# Two applications to different departments at same uni. But: One professor is affiliated with both departments

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, professorship

I would like to apply for PhD programs in two different departments, but at the same uni. I am interested in both fields, but not in the overlap between the two. Generally, this shouldn't be a problem. However, there is a professor associated with both departments. Could this turn out to be a problem? How would you deal with this?

Comment: What makes you think that a professor associated with both departments could be a problem?

Comment: If I apply to department A with SOP A, and for department B with SOP B, and both SOP highlight very different interests, the professor seeing both applications might point out to either department, that I submitted two quite different applications, which could make me look less focused for a PhD program.

Comment: If you can demonstrate a strong case for each, I think it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you've submitted two different applications and they each specify what you're interested in working on, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: well, they would certainly both state what I am interested in, but both applications would state quite *different* interests. (I am applying to two different departments, and, as I said, not because my interests lie in the intersection of the two)

Comment: @M.Fingers then you will probably be fine. What more could you do?